# Почему запрос SQLite3 на вывод из БД возвращает пустой массив?

Tags: sqlite3, php

Запрос SQLite3 на вывод из БД возвращает пустой массив.
Заносит в БД корректно, но не выводит.
Вот код:

```
protected function db2Array($data){
    $arr = array();
    while ($row = $data -> fetchArray(\SQLITE3_ASSOC)){
            $arr[] = $row;
            }
    return $arr;
    }

function getNews() {
    try{
        $sql = "SELECT msgs.id as id, title, category.name as category, description, source, datetime
          FROM msgs, category
          WHERE category.id = msgs.category
          ORDER BY msgs.id DESC";
        $res = $this->_db -> query($sql);
        if(!is_object($res)){
        throw new Exception ($this->_db -> LastErrorMsg());
        }
        return $this->db2Array($res);
        } catch (Exception $exs){
        //$exs -> getMessage(); 
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Запись в БД делал подготовленным запросом. Заносит данные нормально, а выводит (var_dump();): array (size=0) empty. Куда копать? В теле запроса ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполни запрос непосредственно в СУБД, может быть, у тебя SQL-запрос неверный?
Сделай var_dump() на каждом шаге передачи и обработки запроса или воспользуйся xdebug для отладки.

Comment: @get, Спасибо. Запрос кривой. Попробую иначе.